Issues with state tracking when using an onClick event in typescript
I'm just starting to learn React/Typescript so I'm trying to create mini projects to help with my understanding.  I currently have it so I can create different bootstrap 5 button types with different labels and have it output which button was clicked, which is great.  What I'd like to do is figure out how to track changing variables/properties when clicking the button.
I believe the issue has to do with the way I'm either implementing the onClick function or how I'm structuring my function.
Currently, this is what I'm working with:
import { MouseEvent, useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  label: string;
  children: string;
  type: string;
}

const ButtonClass = ({ label, children, type }: Props) => {
  const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (state: boolean, label: string) => {
    console.log(label, "clicked");
    console.log("Old State:", selectedState);
    setSelectedState(!selectedState);
    console.log("New State:", selectedState);
  };

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={type}
      //   onClick={() => console.log(label, "clicked")}
      onClick={handleClick(selectedState, label)}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default ButtonClass;

I think I'm close but the onClick line is saying the following:
"Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler | undefined'.ts(2322)"
I've tried various other approaches, setting button class up as a function (which I probably implemented incorrectly on one side or another).  I'm kinda stuck on where to go from here though, having tried various different things with different incorrect implementations.  I've been able to have it run the "button clicked" portion without issue, I just can't seem to find the correct way to implement the state tracking.
I'm sure there's probably a better component to use for state tracking (I'm sure there's some sort of switch component) but I think this approach will help me understand whatever I'm currently missing, so I think it's a decent approach for the time being.
Any help you can give me would be appreciated.  Thanks!

(1) Change onClick={handleClick(selectedState, label)} to onClick={handleClick}.  (2) Remove arguments to handleClick definition by changing const handleClick = (state: boolean, label: string) => { to const handleClick = () => {. Since it already has everything it needs in scope.

Your core problem is you were calling the handler like onClick={handleClick(selectedState, label)}. It needs a reference to a function that will be called by react when a click happens. If you call it right there, you just passed the return value of the handler, which is nothing (undefined). onClick={handleClick} is a reference to the handler. You will also often see onClick={e=> handleClick()}

Sure enough, that seems to have solved the issue... this makes sense on where my misunderstanding was coming from.  I'm used to C where you pass the arguments in and get the return.  The formatting is a bit less intuitive to me but I'll have to do some more reading.
Any idea why I'm getting this when clicking on the button twice?
button1 clicked
Old State: false
New State: false
button1 clicked
Old State: true
New State: true
Seems to be changing the state but not until it exists the function

Thats because setting state does not immedietely update the value. It is asynchronous and happens on next render. Move the log to the main body of the component. See https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value

Does this answer your question? Pass a JavaScript function as parameter

@adsy That link helped me understand, thanks!  Ended up moving to the following:
const handleClick = () => {     console.log(label, "clicked");     console.log("Old State:", selectedState);     const newState = !selectedState;     setSelectedState(newState);     console.log("New State:", newState);   };

Yep thats fine. Though usually, if you want to see if the state was "really" set, or just log all updates to some state, you'd just log it in the main component body. When react re-renders on state update, you will then see what the current value is.

@adsy you had mentioned adding it to the main component body before but I'm a bit confused as to where that is.  For instance, my Button function is one large return value back to the app component and my app is just displaying my button so I'm not sure where you're referring to by "main component body" (I assume you mean the button since that's the component).  Where would you return/call that?  Would I essentially break my component outside the return, place it there, and then return the result afterwards?  I'm still confused about what you're proposing.  Thanks for your help!

Essentially  anywhere inside of the ButtonClass class function, but at the first level. So as the first line inside of ButtonClass for example, that would be in the "render". Or just above the return statement that returns the JSX. But essentially anywhere inside the "top level" of the component itself. Since the component re-renders every time state changes, its a useful place to log state.
